# Get data using spring repository when relation one to many

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

So I have two classes Movie and Genres in relation one-to-many. What I want to do is to get List of Movies filtred by Genres name using Spring repositorys.
I want to be able to do something like:

```
List<Movie> movies = movieRepository.getMoviesByGenres(Arrays.asList("Drama", "Comedy"))
```

I was tring to do it like belowe, but this not wokrs, is there any option to do this using spring repository?

```
@Entity
public class Movie {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "movie_id")
  private long id;
  private String title;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie")
  private Set<Genres> genres;
  ...
}
```

-

```
@Entity
public class Genres {

  @Id
  private long id;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", nullable = false)
  private Movie movie;
  private String name;
  ...
}
```

-

```
public interface MovieRepository extends JpaRepository<Movie, Long>{

  List<Movie> getMoviesByGenres(String name);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a method like below:

```
public interface MovieRepository extends JpaRepository<Movie, Long>{

  List<Movie> getMoviesByGenresNameIn(List<String> names);
}
```

And if you want to fetch `geners` relation with one query you need to decorate the method with `EntityGraph` like below:

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths={"geners"})
List<Movie> getMoviesByGenresNameIn(List<String> names);
```